# Waiting for snapshot value inside a map in Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm receiving an Object from that has a list of products ids and its database's ref, so I must search for each product in my database to get its price, I've tried something like this

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const cors = require('cors')({
    origin: true
});
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
var request = require('request');
admin.initializeApp();
exports.GeraPagSeguro = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    cors(req, res, () => {
            if (req.method === 'POST') {
                var xml;
                req.body.map((product) => {
                    admin.database().ref(product.refitem).once('value', (snapshot) => {
                        const value = snapshot.val();
                        const price = value.price;
                        xml += price;
                        //rest of code building the xml i want
                    })
                })
                //rest of code sending the xml via POST to other server
            })
    })
})
```

The problem is that the rest of the code doesn't `wait` for all the promises of the `map`.

Comment: I don't think so, I'm kinda new to node.js and firebase, req.body is just a plain javascript object

Comment: My bad, I mistook it for something else, check out my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To wait for multiple asynchronous operations to complete, use `Promise.all()`:

```
var xml;
var promises = [];
req.body.map((product) => {
    promises.push(admin.database().ref(product.refitem).once('value', (snapshot) => {
        const value = snapshot.val();
        const price = value.price;
        return price;
    })
})
Promise.all(promises).then((prices) => {
    prices.forEach((price) => {
        ...
    });
    //rest of code sending the xml via POST to other server
});
```

Comment: When I try to deploy the function I'm getting an error `Parsing error: Unexpected token Promise` on this line `let prices = await Promise.all(promises)`

Comment: Interesting. You might want to try it with a `Promise.all(promises).then(prices => {});` instead then.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen by default async functions are not enabled in the Firebase functions set up, you have to specify some things in the configuration file to make it work. See my answer

Comment: Using `Promise.all(promises).then(prices => {});` worked, thanks

Comment: OK. Updated to reflect that. It might be that you can't use `await` at the top level, or that you were missing an `async` annotation on the function declaration itself. Honestly: I use `Promise.then()` way more still, so am not fully used to `async`/`await` in Cloud Functions.

Answer (score 1):

Since the firebase database function returns a `Promise`, you can turn you function into an async function and call `await` on it. Like this:

```
exports.GeraPagSeguro = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    cors(req, res, () => {
            if (req.method === 'POST') {
                var xml;
                req.body.map((product) => {
                    const snapshot = await admin.database().ref(product.refitem).once('value')
                    const value = snapshot.val();
                    const price = value.price;
                    xml += price;
                    //rest of code building the xml i want
                })
                //rest of code sending the xml via POST to other server
            })
    })
})
```

Then you can execute you other code like they "waited" for the firebase operation

---

**Note**: Async functions are not enabled in the default Firebase functions set up, you need to specify the `emcaVersion` to 2017 or 8 (default is 7) in the `.eslintrc.json` file to make sure Async related functions work. It should look like this:

```
{
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 2017 //or 8
    }
}
```

Besides that, you need to also add `promise` as plugin, like this:

```
"plugins": [
    "promise"
 ]
```

If you have anything in `.eslintrc.json` that specifies `es6` usage, change it to `es7`.

Comment: It seems I couldn't use this `async function` because I wasn't using `  "engines": {
    "node": "8"
  }` on my package-json, but now I'm getting this error `Parsing error: Unexpected token admin`

Comment: I got that error before as well, you need to have `"parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 2017
  }` in your `.eslintrc.json` file to make async work

Comment: also add `"plugins": [
    "promise"
  ],`

Comment: my .eslintrc.json also have `"plugins": [ "promise" ]`

Comment: also, do you have anything like env that specifies es6?

Comment: If you have anything in `.eslintrc.json` that specifies es6, change it to es7

Comment: Really tried to implement this but I couldn't make this ecmascript 7/engine 8 thing to work, @Frank van Puffelen answer worked in my case